# program is getting stuck at pthread_spin_unlock statement when optimizations (O1 or O2 or O3) are turned on

Tags: c++, optimization, synchronization, pthreads, compiler-optimization

I am writing a program which has 8 threads. I am implementing a barrier which has a global count that is incremented by each thread when it possesses the lock. All threads wait in a while loop for this count to become 8 and when it becomes 8 they are supposed to proceed. I am seeing that only the thread that made the count from 7 to 8 actually ends up proceeding while all other threads are stuck at the unlock statement that follows the increment. All of this happens only when either of O1, O2 or O3 optimizations are turned on.

code is

```
// some code

pthread_spin_lock (&lcl_mutex_1);
sync_count_1++; // global count 
pthread_spin_unlock (&lcl_mutex_1);

while (isbreak_1 == 0) {
    if (sync_count_1==8) {
         cout << a << endl; //a is argument that indicated the thread number.
         isbreak_1=1;
    }
}

// some code
```

This entire process works fine when no optimizations are turned on.

Here's what I verified. i compiled with -O3 and -g on. put a break point at the

```
cout << a << endl;
```

line. I saw that the thread that updates the count to 8 is the only one to hit this break point. when i used "info threads" to see the status of other threads, all of them were stuck at pthread_spin_unlock statement.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Adding

```
//global declaration

pthread_spinlock_t lcl_mutex_1

//in main

pthread_spin_init (&lcl_mutex_1, 0);
```

I compiled the code using
    g++ -DUSE_SPINLOCK -O3 -g corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp -lpthread

I will copy and paste the gdb output as well

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x40a00940 (LWP 30485)]
[New Thread 0x41401940 (LWP 30486)]
[New Thread 0x41e02940 (LWP 30487)]
[New Thread 0x42803940 (LWP 30488)]
[New Thread 0x43204940 (LWP 30489)]
[New Thread 0x43c05940 (LWP 30490)]
[New Thread 0x44606940 (LWP 30491)]
[New Thread 0x45007940 (LWP 30492)]
Time is 53      0 //these are some time measurements I have made before the prolematic section
Time is 51      1
Time is 51      4
Time is 51      5
Time is 51      2
Time is 51      6
Time is 51      3
[Thread 0x2aaaaaabfc10 (LWP 30482) exited]
[Switching to Thread 0x44606940 (LWP 30491)]

Breakpoint 1, calc_corr (t=0x6) at corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:337
337                                     cout << a << endl;
(gdb) info threads
9 Thread 0x45007940 (LWP 30492)  0x00000000004033e4 in calc_corr (t=0x7) at  corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:334
* 8 Thread 0x44606940 (LWP 30491)  calc_corr (t=0x6) at corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:337
7 Thread 0x43c05940 (LWP 30490)  0x00000000004033e4 in calc_corr (t=0x5) at corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:334
6 Thread 0x43204940 (LWP 30489)  0x00000000004033e4 in calc_corr (t=0x4) at corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:334
5 Thread 0x42803940 (LWP 30488)  0x00000000004033e4 in calc_corr (t=0x3) at corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:334
4 Thread 0x41e02940 (LWP 30487)  0x00000000004033e4 in calc_corr (t=0x2) at corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:334
3 Thread 0x41401940 (LWP 30486)  0x00000000004033e4 in calc_corr (t=0x1) at corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:334
2 Thread 0x40a00940 (LWP 30485)  0x00000000004033e4 in calc_corr (t=0x0) at corr_coeff_parallel_v9.cpp:334
(gdb)
```

Comment: And `sync_count_1`. It needs to be `volatile`. Though that wouldn't cause the hang in unlock.

Comment: What is `sync_count_1`? Accessing it un-synchronized may also be a problem.

Comment: You need to hold the spin lock when you access `sync_count_1`. The code in your while loop does not. Fix that bug and I bet your problem will go away.

Comment: @smparkes Using `volatile` is neither necessary nor sufficient -- so why do it? ("It happened to work when I tried it" is not an acceptable answer to that question.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz is it not? Any ref, for my edification? My presumption was the access to `sync_count_1` is atomic and that the posix stuff is coded to put the necessary barriers in there .... but that's not true/not enough?

Comment: sync_count_1 within the spinlock will provide the needed memory barriers, but it's read outside a spinlock as well, in which there's no memory barriers, so it should be volatile. Though the OP should rather use the pthread_barrier_wait family.. Also, note that gdb line numbers are usually incorrect when you enable optimization.

Comment: Yeah, FWIW, I didn't mean to imply you didn't need the mutex, but that if you were going read it outside the mutex, it needed to be volatile. But if _that's_ not sufficient, I'd be interested in hearing. I am presuming that `sync_count_1` is chosen to be atomic.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I locked it before reading it each time and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @nos thanks, I did not know about pthread_barrier_wait, that was stupid of me. Well gdb line numbers yes, I generally set break points relative the file

Comment: @smparkes Since the POSIX functions are guaranteed to be sufficient by the pthreads standard,`volatile` is not necessary. Since `volatile` has no precisely-defined semantics in a multi-threaded program, it's not necessary. If it's not necessary and it's not sufficient, what good does it do? Instead, just use something that is guaranteed sufficient (such as spinlocks).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I was looking for a solution that didn't require a lock on reading. It's still not clear to me why `volatile` is not sufficient in this particular case. I understand why it doesn't work in then general case.

Comment: @smparkes Of course it's not clear to you, it has no documented semantics in this case. Check the pthreads standard. Check the C++ standard. You'll find nothing that tells you that `volatile` will do what is required in this case. (If you want a solution that doesn't require a lock on reading, you need atomic operations with defined inter-thread memory visibility semantics.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: well, it says it'll do an observable read against the standard's VM model. For it to work, it requires the assumption of extra-standard behavior to guarantee that the read is atomic. As far as I can see, there are no barrier requirements here (outside what the posix calls are guaranteed to do.) That's the only reason I'm even following up: it's not that your solution isn't right, but I wonder if I'm missing an aspect of the memory models/archs that I think I understand but don't.

Comment: @smparkes: There is a barrier requirement here -- he needs a guarantee that the read in the `while` loop will eventually see a write made by another thread. POSIX doesn't guarantee that without a lock. Nothing about the semantics of `volatile` guarantees inter-thread memory visibility. (Check the C/C++ standards. They say nothing about memory visibility.) All you know about his memory model or arch is that it supports the C++ and pthreads standards. If, say, his arch required a special instruction to see changes made by another thread, there's no guarantee a volatile read would have it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "If, say, his arch required a special instruction to see changes made by another thread, there's no guarantee a volatile read would have it." Do you know of any arch that has instructions like this, barriers on either the writing or reading thread? I don't know of any and I'd like to, if they exist. And I don't mean to imply whether there are or not is relevant to this question. Architectural interest on my part.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8202/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-smparkes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX standard makes accessing an object in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it undefined behavior. Your code does this, by accessing `sync_count_1` in the `while` loop while another thread might be modifying it. The simplest fix is to hold the spinlock during the read. Another solution would be to use a library (or compiler-specific intrinsic, or assembly code) that provides an atomic memory operation with defined inter-thread memory visibility semantics.